# Behaviour of nil receiver in method in Golang

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type I interface {
    M()
}

type T struct {

}

func (t *T) M() {
    fmt.Println(t == nil)
}

func main() {
    var i I
    var t *T

    i = t

    fmt.Println(i == nil)

    i.M()
}
```

The result is `false` and `true`.

The value in both cases is `nil` and type is `*main.T`.

I understand that in the first case `i == nil` is `false` because the variable `i` does not have a `nil` type.

I do not understand why `t == nil` is `true` inside the method `M()`.

Comment: Note: It is important to avoid having a nil value in a non-nil interface. It is hard to deal with.

Answer (score 9):

In the first case, `i==nil` is false, because `i` is an interface whose type is `T` and whose value is `nil`. For an interface to be equal to the literal value `nil`, it has to have both type and value `nil`. Here, `i` has non-nil type.

In the second case, the receiver is simply nil, because the receiver of the function `M` is a value of type `*T` whose value is `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see the difference now.